# C++: GetTempPath() without tilde (~)

Tags: c++, windows

I need to get temp path. So I tried GetTempPath() and std::getenv("TEMP"). The problem is that the result contains ~ symbol, for example C:\Users\OLEKSI~1.ALE\AppData\Local\Temp.
Is it possible to get full temp path like C:\Users\Oleksii\AppData\Local\Temp?

Comment: [`GetLongPathName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlongpathnamea)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetLongPathName` function:

> Converts the specified path to its long form.

```
DWORD GetLongPathNameW(
  [in]  LPCWSTR lpszShortPath,
  [out] LPWSTR  lpszLongPath,
  [in]  DWORD   cchBuffer
);

DWORD GetLongPathNameA(
  [in]  LPCSTR lpszShortPath,
  [out] LPSTR  lpszLongPath,
  [in]  DWORD  cchBuffer
);
```

Set `lpszShortPath` = short path with `~` symbols. Read result from `lpszLongPath`.

[GetLongPathName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlongpathnamew)

Answer (score -1):

According to [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppatha):

> The GetTempPath function checks for the existence of environment variables in the following order and uses the first path found:
>
> - The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
> - The path specified by the TEMP environment variable.
> - The path specified by the USERPROFILE environment variable.
> - The Windows directory.

Have you checked what these are set to? In Windows 10 you can press Windows+Break to open System Settings, then click Advanced system settings on the right, then click Environment Variables. If TMP, TEMP or USERPROFILE are in there, check that they are set correctly and don't have the unwanted `~` in them. If they're not, try adding them.

Comment: the shortcut is Windows+Break, not Ctrl+Break

Comment: They are both C:\Users\Oleksii\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: Apologies, I meant Windows+Break, just wrote the wrong word. Looks like Alex F has the correct answer anyway. Considered deleting my answer, but will leave it up in case it helps anyone else for whom this is the reason.